# Use Jalali calendar

Tags: calendar

I want to use Jalali calendar in my store, I use a plugin that have some `js` and `css` files that I add these files in `skin/default/my-theme/js` and `skin/default/my-theme/css` and also in `local.xml`.

Now I don't know how can I use this calendar in back-end and front-end?

Answer (score 2):

use this code:-
  `<link rel="stylesheet" href="jalalijscalendar/skins/aqua/theme.css">
    <script src="jalalijscalendar/jalali.js"></script>
    <script src="jalalijscalendar/calendar.js"></script>
    <script src="jalalijscalendar/calendar-setup.js"></script>
      <script src="jalalijscalendar/lang/calendar-fa.js"></script>
     <input id="date_input" type="text"><input id="date_btn" type="button">
    <script>
    Calendar.setup({
        inputField: 'date_input',
        button: 'date_btn',
        ifFormat: '%Y/%m/%d',
        dateType: 'jalali'
    });
    </script>`

https://www.dropbox.com/s/5s6yetwl5xcylhi/JalaliJSCalendar-1.4.tar.gz?dl=0

Comment: Add this code in which file?

Comment: Is ok add this code in head.html?

Comment: Can you explain me about the attachment in dropbox?how can I use it?

Comment: I don't know how can I use these files.

Comment: first magento->js folder change

Comment: There is a setting for the calendar. It is called hiliteToday. If you change in js/calendar/calendar.js: this.hiliteToday = true; to this.hiliteToday = false;

Comment: I mean that the `js` and `css` files in this attachment I should add in `skin/default/my-theme/js and css`? then how can I use it?

Comment: i not use but i am pratice how can change